# Перевести массив с секундами в формат мин/сек

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

У меня есть массив numpy в Python под названием Time: [29454. 29458. 29462. ... 30030. 30034. 30038. 30042.], который содержит 148 значений в секундах, с интеpвалом времени = 4 сек. Как перевести эти данные в формат минута/секунда и изобразить на графике с указанием начального и конечного времени. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: можете пояснить что вы ожидаете увидеть на графике? Какие данные будут отображаться на оси `X` и какие на оси `Y`? В данном случае не помешал бы эскиз графика, чтобы было понятно что вы хотите нарисовать...

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо за быструю реакцию. По оси Y у меня есть значения, которые отображают распределение энергии. По оси X хотела бы увидеть указанный выше временной интевал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Модуль Pandas выполнит всю "грязную работу" за вас.

Пример:

Пусть нам дан Numpy вектор секунд в переменной `a`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# преобразовываем секунды в дату/время (`datetime`)    
d = pd.to_datetime(a, unit='s')

# случайные данные для имитации
vals = np.random.rand(len(d), 3)

# создаем Pandas DataFrame со временем в качестве индекса:    
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=d, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

# рисуем график:
df.plot(figsize=(12, 6))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

получившийся DataFrame:

```
In [93]: df
Out[93]:
                         col1      col2      col3
1970-01-01 08:10:54  0.523823  0.052046  0.636861
1970-01-01 08:10:58  0.535050  0.497951  0.374262
1970-01-01 08:11:02  0.172070  0.633870  0.317011
1970-01-01 08:11:06  0.513052  0.377725  0.466321
1970-01-01 08:11:10  0.249807  0.526408  0.397610
1970-01-01 08:11:14  0.664661  0.961287  0.766001
1970-01-01 08:11:18  0.231235  0.268803  0.527237
1970-01-01 08:11:22  0.375289  0.015268  0.831675
1970-01-01 08:11:26  0.678696  0.776896  0.858039
1970-01-01 08:11:30  0.827448  0.965021  0.656427
...                       ...       ...       ...
1970-01-01 08:20:06  0.986316  0.853867  0.310788
1970-01-01 08:20:10  0.677466  0.369037  0.145889
1970-01-01 08:20:14  0.100703  0.323591  0.442225
1970-01-01 08:20:18  0.052108  0.108151  0.059627
1970-01-01 08:20:22  0.902023  0.267589  0.074370
1970-01-01 08:20:26  0.025258  0.443323  0.475542
1970-01-01 08:20:30  0.636909  0.292724  0.743920
1970-01-01 08:20:34  0.733317  0.785113  0.792359
1970-01-01 08:20:38  0.271341  0.418553  0.434469
1970-01-01 08:20:42  0.324157  0.935925  0.759365

[148 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: @u_lialia, пожалуйста :-)